# Resetting Twitter Bootstrap form radio button group. How?

Tags: jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with Twitter Bootstrap and Joomla 3.0  and have a form that I need to reset to default. Simple `form.reset();` works on all elements except radio btn group.

I mean , the radio gets reset but the label state is not changing. I had few failed attempts to reset it but it is backfiring because of ambiguous btn class names . I tried to  target fieldset groups with id in a form with over 50 radio button options and did not work out well. Their colors end up being different and so on.

I would appreciate any help on this

here is fiddle with examples

http://jsfiddle.net/DZ7HL/31/

The js for  **Turn radios into btn-group** comes from joomla default administrator template and **I cannot remove / edit or change it** , if that is causing some trouble I have to find way for this to work with that js being present.  I have my own js file that is loading after that one if that is of any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution I went for is

```
// FROM HERE IS CHANGABLE
$('#reset_form').click(function() {

    $('#myform')[0].reset();


    $(".btn-group label:not(.active)").change(function() {
        var label = $(this);
        var input = $('#' + label.attr('for'));

        if (input.prop('checked')) {
            label.closest('.btn-group').find("label").removeClass('active btn-success btn-danger btn-primary');
            if (input.val() == '') {
                label.addClass('active btn-primary');
            } else if (input.val() == 0) {
                label.addClass('active btn-danger');
            } else {
                label.addClass('active btn-success');
            }
        }
    }).change();




})​
```

as shown here,  jsfiddle.net/Yt9uX/41   so there you have it I am sure it will come in handy to anyone working with joomla 3.0 or bootsrtap forms that use btn groups for radios

Comment: GW! The last line in the change function `input.prop('checked', true);` seems to be unnessecary - it is already true. Well, good night! :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the strange "logic" joomla does with the labels. It adds some classes to the labels, you can easily reset the radiogroup, but the "manual" added classes stay, so you have to remove them.

All the "defaults" is #2 option, right? Here is a generic function to do that

```
// FROM HERE IS CHANGABLE
function resetRadioGroup(groupname) {
switch($("input[name='"+groupname+"']:eq(1)").val()) {
    case '' : var css='btn-primary'; break;
    case '0': var css='btn-danger'; break;
    default : var css='btn-success'; break;
}
$("input[name='"+groupname+"']").next().removeClass('active btn-success');
$("input[name='"+groupname+"']:eq(1)").prop("checked", true).next().addClass('active '+css);
}

$('#reset_form').click(function() {
    $('#myform')[0].reset();
    resetRadioGroup('radio_test');
    resetRadioGroup('radio2_test');
})
```

​
have forked it on http://jsfiddle.net/AtL5q/

**UPDATE**
Given that all radiogroups is in a fieldset with the class btn-group, you can automate the call to the `resetRadioGroup` function :

```
$('#reset_form').click(function() {
    $('#myform')[0].reset();
    $('fieldset.btn-group').each(function() {
      resetRadioGroup($(this).find('input').first().attr('name'));
    });
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3aU4F/

Comment: nice solution , but I must see how I can implement it without naming the fields id's , since I have min 20 of them .  I am also on to something here
http://jsfiddle.net/Yt9uX/41/

works fine but seems to be problem with closest()  it freezes the page for few seconds until it finds it and joomla backend is garbled with mootools and jquery so I think mootools is messing with it . Il try your solution it is a nice step forward.

Comment: excelent but joomla , o boy ,  fieldnames start with jform_params_ prefix and radio name jform[params][PREFIX_field_name] so crazy. I managed to have it work with my edit   jsfiddle.net/Yt9uX/41 , just placed it in a loop that I did not see , works perfect now. thank you for all the effort it helped alot!

Comment: OK! Cant help with joomla, know nothing about it. It seems/sounds rather "closed" or inflexible, like the stuff with css classes assigned to the labels. Well, hope you get through with your project!